# Is this given set with given properties a basis for this subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field, $V$ an infinite set. For each $v\in V$, $e_v(x)=1$ whenever $v=x$ and $e_v(x)=0$ whenever $v\neq x$. Let $U$ be the subset of the set of functions from $V$ to $\mathbb{F}$ such that $f(v)=0$ for all, but finitely many $v \in V$. Is $\{e_v: v \in V\}$ a basis for U?

I am confused as to how to approach this question. First, I thought about showing whether the set we are checking to be a basis is linearly independent.

If $\{e_v: v \in V\}$ is to be a basis for $U$, I must show that for some scalars $a_1,\dots,a_n \in \mathbb{F}$, I have that $a_1e_1(x) + \cdots + a_ne_n  (x) = 0$ only when $a_1,\dots,a_n=0$. I think this to be the case, since whenever I have $v=x$ for some $e_v(x)$, then all the other $e_i(x)'s$ where $i\neq x$ go to zero, so i'm left with some $a_ie_i(x)$, which is only zero if and only if $a_i=0$. Hence all the $a_i's$ must be zero.

Now, if my argument is correct, it remains to show that the set of all linear combinations with vectors $e_1,\dots,e_n$ with scalars $a_1,\dots,a_n$ spans $U$. How does one check this? I'm confused as to how the set of functions from $V$ to $\mathbb{F}$ such that $f(v)=0$ even plays a role ni this question.

Comment: @user251257 I meant $V$ to $\mathbb{F}$

Comment: Just write out an arbitrary element of $V$ as a finite linear combination of the $e_x$'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if $f \in U$ is non-zero exactly at ${v_1, .., v_n}$, then

$$
f \equiv f(v_1)e_{v_1} + .... + f(v_n)e_{v_n}
$$

since if $v \notin \{v_1, ..., v_n\} $,

$$
f(v_1)e_{v_1}(v) + .... + f(v_n)e_{v_n}(v) = 0 = f(v)
$$

and if $v \in \{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ , $v = v_i$ for $i \in \{1, .. , n\}$,
$$
f(v_1)e_{v_1}(v_i) + .... + f(v_n)e_{v_n}(v_i) = f(v_i)e_{v_i}(v_i) = f(v_i)
$$

And so we've written every element of $U$ as a finite linear combination of elements of the $e_v$'s.